# How can i display a red border in a text area when it doesnt fulfill the requirements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form with two input fields and a text area. In my js file i have this requirments:

```
rules: {
                name: { //input field
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 40,
                    diffname: true
                },
                email: { //input field
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    diffmail : true
                },
                message: { //textarea
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 50,
                    diffname: true
                }
            }
```

In my css file I have an error class that turns borders into red when the fields have an error after submit. Here is my class:

```
input.error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
        }
```

and here is my html form:

```
<form method="post" id="send">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" /></br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" /></br>
<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></br>
<button name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that this is working only for the input fields and not for the text area.

Comment: Share your html because you are using `input.error{}` my guess is that you need to target the "text" but without seeing the html we cannot target the right element for you

Comment: try changing your css selector to `input.error, textarea.error { border: 1px solid #f00; }`

Comment: instead of using input.error, just have it be .error

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar is right add textarea.error too in css.

Comment: Just .error would also make it easier if you have to support drop downs.

Comment: I had tried it before but i found the "mistake". In an other class in the css file I had a border color for the textarea and since I removed it worked!

Answer (score 4):

This should do it for you:

```
input.error, textarea.error {border: 1px solid #f00;}
```

Since you are only targeting the `input` elements, you need to also target the `textarea` elements

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jftf8a39/6/

Answer (score 3):

Either change input.error{ ... to

```
input.error, textarea.error { ...
```

or just

```
.error{ ...
```